# How to get online audio streaming from a website with different urls?

Tags: android

I have got a website which shows a list of audio files mp3 format. Each one is having their own URL. I want to know how could I read all the files url into my app and use it for audio streaming? Main emphasis is own how to read the url.

Answer (score 1):

you should parse it(your website) to get all url and play it(the song or list of songs) one by one or in list
this may help you to start :

`String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); 
mediaPlayer.start();`